# Rails making new cron jobs based on user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, background-process, whenever, cron-task

In my application, I want to invoke an action every two weeks based on when the user triggered an action. I guess what's confusing is why there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of doing this.

Ideally, the repeated job would be set *in the model*, **not some other file**. For example, the `whenever` gem has these [instructions](https://github.com/javan/whenever#getting-started):

> ### Getting started
>
> `$ cd /apps/my-great-project`
>
> `$ wheneverize .`
>
> This will create initial `config/schedule.rb` file for you.

But I don't want to put my schedules in there. I want the schedule to be in my model. The schedule isn't being set by me, it's being set by my users.

Is there any straightforward way of implementing this? I've been stumped on this for weeks.

Comment: Could you have the cron job run regularly (every 1/2 hour) and store the date in the Model where it would only run if it passed a test based on the user action?

Answer (score 0):

You could use delayed-job.

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

Your users could define jobs that are stored in your model. You would create the first delayed job and after each completed job you can start a new delayed job.

If your user creates a job that should run at 3:00 am and he saves that job at 3:00 pm you need to create the first job:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(CronJob.new(params[:id]), 1, 12.hours.from_now )
```

Before starting this job you would create tne next job

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(CronJob.new(params[:id]), 1, 1.days.from_now )
```