# How can I create custom cron jobs past on a date picker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have the following feature on a web app:

[image]

For the picture above, I save the time specified on a `Schedule` model for some work to be performed. At the moment this works perfectly for "Simple" selections meaning that if a user selects `Hourly, Weekly, Daily, or Monthly` only, then I have a fleet of cron jobs that will start `Hourly, Weekly, Daily, or Monthly`. So just to be clear, I have  4 cron jobs already placed in my crontab that will run at the specified time and pick the corresponding schedule models.

The problem that I'm facing is the Custom feature. I'm stumped as to how I can effectively create a background task to run on custom input for a user. Here is an example scenario. Let's say I have 3 users who each select a custom time to perform some work.

User 1 selects a custom task to be done on January, February, and March only.
User 2 selects a custom task to be done on Mondays at 1, 3, 6, and 9 pm.
User 3 selects a scan to be done on Friday through Saturday every month only.

And the customization goes on and on.......

What would be an effective and feasible way of implementing this kind of behavior? For the moment, I'm stumped and haven't come up with a way to even approach this based on the requirement. From what I have read, I believe a delayed job will help me based on this stack overflow question [custom job based on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814342/rails-making-new-cron-jobs-based-on-user-input/18827619#18827619) but with so much variability, how would this be possible. Some help and guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go with a mechanism that enqueues the job once for the next occurrence when the configuration is saved. Then, after it has been run, calculate the next occurrence and so on. Don't forget to first remove the already-scheduled run when making changes to the configuration. This can be tricky with some ActiveJob adapters which is why, in case you haven't made a decision towards a specific one yet, I'd like to recommend [que](https://github.com/que-rb/que). But you can do it [in Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API), too.

To facilitate calculation of the next occurrence, you could use, for example, the [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) gem.